# Vim C++ (Qt, C) development powerful plugins

Tags: c++, qt, vim, development-environment

I want to try vim (I use linux) in development, but there are many plugins with lots of documentation, so it's hard to find plugins I want.

I'm going to use: C++, Qt, C. So this is what I need from plugins:

1) `Code completion`:

1.1) Complete `everything` and `smart` (including nested templates and include files) from standard library, side libraries, my sources. (the popup with possible completes must show function arguments and result, so I can see overloaded functions). I don't bother how it should be organized, but I need to tell completer which libraries I want and where all the project files are located.

1.2) The completer `must` show the help info (function template) until I finish it. 
I'll try to explain it:

```
foo.bar(a.firstArg(p1, p2), b.secondArg(p3, p4, p5))
```

when I typed `foo.bar(` I still want to see the help information about the `foo.bar` 
function and it's arguments.
Then when I type `a.fir` I want to select with, for example, `tab` and complete the `a.firstArg(` and the new information about the `a.firstArg` function and arguments should be shown until I write `a.firstArg(p1, p2)`. Of cource when I write `p1` it should complete it, and then after I write `,` the info about `a.firstArg` is shown again. So I finish this nested statement, then when I write `,` the popup about `foo.bar` arguments are shown again. And so on until I finish the statement.

So I want to see all information about the unfinished statement all the time, until I finish the statement. If there are several overloaded functions, I want be able to choose which info I want to see.

1.3) It would be nice to have fast autocomplete menu and ability to 
select forward and backward.

2) `Navigation` (this should work in a pair with the completer, so it should 
take the about libraries, sources that I provide to completer and use it for navigation):

2.1) Go to declaration of the symbol under cursor.

2.2) Switch between declaration and definition. (Or go to definition).

2.3) Switch between foo.h and foo.cpp (foo.c)

2.4) Get back several jumps. (So I could go to declaration, then go to definition, then go to declaration of some function I saw there and then switch to cpp file, and then got back to default position (maybe in the same amount of jumps)).

3) Code generation:

3.1) Create `foo.h` and `foo.c(pp)` with `_FOO_H_` include guard and `#include "foo.h"` in `foo.c(pp)`

3.2) For the declared function in `foo.h` I want to create definition in `foo.c(pp)`. Moreover the position of the created definition should be the same as in header file. And moreover if I have a declaration in `foo.cpp` and use this function, than it should create the definition in the same file `foo.cpp`.

3.3) There should be easy to create code generation templates, so I could create my own 
template to generate, for example, `pimpl` idiom. (the code should appear in header and source files at one moment). For example:

I write: `:pimpl Test` when the `foo.h` is active and get:

```
//foo.h
class Test{
public:
private:
  class Impl_;
  Impl_ *m_i;
};

//foo.cpp
class Test::Impl_{
public:
private:
}
```

What did I tried.

I found `YouCompleteMe` but I didn't found how to get the `1.2)` behavior. Moreover the ycm server crashes with it's own `libclang.so` so I use system clang. And there are always some messy messages like `template not found(^N^P^U)`. So I can't understand is this a bug or a feature. Anyway, I tried `clang_complete` but there is a similar behavior. For the code generation I found several snippet plugins, but I didn't study them too much, because if I couldn't find the appropriate code completion and navigation, there is no sense to use vim for me.

So it would be nice if someone will tell me where to search...

Comment: You sound like you want an IDE, not a text editor.

Comment: @romainl Actually I want only a part of an DE. And almost only a text related part. I don't need automatic build settings or debugging with breakpoints. I don't need to save a project state or integrated version control. I don't need gui to setup compile options and i don't need other IDE benefits. I just need smart text analysis and comfortable text completion, navigation and generation. Everything else I can do outside editor.

Comment: Try asking on [softwarerecs.se], , but make sure you follow their [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336).

Comment: Sorry (I cannot answer at the proper place any more). 2.2. I use :GOTOIMPL from my lh-cpp suite (https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp ). 2.3. I use alternate (there exist other solutions since then). 3. I use my fork of mu-template+lh-cpp. It doesn't provide a pimpl generator yet (It'll be easy to add), but you'll found everything you asked regarding new files (proper header generation; foo.c(pp) will include foo.h(pp...) if found, and even include the file in the right path -> #include "module/submodule/foo.h", ...)

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that, even with multiple plugins, Vim, at its core, is a general purpose editor, and can't really compete with a dedicated IDE for a specific language.

For code completion,  `YouCompleteMe` seems to be the most popular at the moment. If you have a specific question on the configuration it would be easier to deal with in an alternate question with appropriate tags.

On Navigation

2.1 You should install ctags or cscope

2.2 ctags with `:tn` and `:tp`

2.3 Look for a.vim

2.4 There is a jump list, you can go forward/backward with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>. Check `:help jump`. You can also use marks `:help mark`.

For generic navigation (not code based), I would also recommend `Ctrl-P`.

On Code Generation

You can use a mix of Snipmate (plugin) which is pretty extensible and your own macro (using abbr, etc).

Vim is really about configuring/developing your own solution rather than getting a full package with everything installed.

And generally, as a regular vim user, I think the code completion, generation, refactoring parts of Vim is inferior to a dedicated IDE most of the time. I have played with Eclim for a while, nowadays I basically switch between Vim and IDE (with Vim mode if possible) depending on what I am doing at the moment.